# Rails send_file to video/audio tags don't let me replay the video/audio or jump to different points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, audio, video

In my Rails app, I have audio and video files in a location I wish to make private, so they can only be accessed by send_file or send_data. When I use send_file for an action that gets put inside of a source src="(controller/action)" tag, the video/audio shows up in the browser. However, unlike with video/audio files in the Rails public folder, I cannot jump to different parts of the audio with the default player GUI, nor can I loop the video/audio, etc. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

*Edit:* This problem seems to only happen with chrome.